# no scope found WSO2API manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have configured WSO2 API Manager integrated with WSO2 Identity server.
I have created some API's and created some scopes , roles to it..
But currently i cant see any scopes in the applications ,when i try to generate key..

What could be the reason? I have been changing many configuration files for deploying this in EC2.Could any of them cause this issue?I have no errros in console..how can i debug this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only the scopes which are assigned to API resources will be shown there.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bhathiya mentioned we need set scope on resource of API.

Please refer this article for more details on how to set scope for resource. [[Article] How to Use OAuth 2.0 Scopes to Provide Role-Based Authorization to APIs Exposed via WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/12/article-role-based-access-control-for-apis-exposed-via-wso2-api-manager-using-oauth-2.0-scopes/) by Nadeesha Gamage.

I have tried myself and it worked. PFA Screenprint.

**1. Set Scope on resource.**
[image: Set Scope]
**2. Scope was available to generate key**
[image: generate key with scope]

I have set the roles to user while testing. In your case you need define roles in integrated wso2 identity server.